# Depth textures clamped to 1.0?

Tags: directx, directx-11

I'm doing exponential shadow maps where instead of outputing depth, I output exp(depth), like this:

```
float ps_main(float4 position : SV_Position) : SV_Depth
{
    return exp(position.z / position.w);
}
```

Using exp() just turns the entire depth texture to white (1.0f).

I am thinking that no depth gets written because the depth texture is cleared to 1.0f, which is max, and all exp() values are equal or higher. How can I get around this? I want to write any float value to the depth texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SV_Depth` range is determined by the depth min/max in the viewport, and has a maximum range of 0.0 to 1.0 (it is effectively a `UNORM` surface interpretation).  Any invocations with depth values outside this range or greater than the current value of the depth buffer are discarded.  If you want to encode the expression in your code, you can either calculate it on load whenever you end up using it, or write it to a separate render target (e.g. `R32_FLOAT`) rather than using the depth buffer.